# HTC Desire cannot connect with HTC Sync

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 2.2-froyo, htc-desire

I recently received an HTC Desire as a gift with no SD card. It was updated to Froyo. I'd like to update it further to Gingerbread, however I cannot get any version of HTC Sync to recognize my phone.

- I've tried several versions
- I've disabled firewall and antivirus
- I've run HTC Sync in compatibility mode and as administrator
- I've rebooted both phone and PC
- I'm sure I've tried other things that I forgot to list.

The standard answer to this seems to be 'install the HTC Sync version that is on your SD card', but I don't have the original card. I have been unable to find out which version of HTC Sync that was originally included.

Does anyone know which version of HTC Sync I need for my HTC Desire to connect?

Comment: Is this the original Desire (i.e. a8181), because I do have the original desire and can check.

Answer (score 0):

It is the original desire. It seems to have come with 2.0.28 which I can't find anywhere. I did find 2.0.33 which also didn't work.